# JQuery get external data periodically without reloading page

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi I would like to check an external file which is running a sql query to see if a status value of 0 has changed to 1. And if so redirect to a another page.

I have made a call using a GET and this works fine.

However when I attemept to get it to check every 2 seconds using a setTimeout it does not seem to run more then once.

I have tried to work this out for hours and I just cant get my head around it, please help!

```
(function loop(){
        $.get("statusPage.jsp", function(data){
        var loadedData = data;
        if(data == 1){
            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
        }
    });
    setTimeout(loop,2000)
})();
```

Comment: Why are you setting `data` to a variable and not even use it?

Comment: Oversight, been playing with the code for hours so it must have sliped in. Any ideas on the solution by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have managed to fix this.

I am a total noob when it comes to Javascipts. I thought I could use my Java knowledge to work it out. But it was a lot harder then I thought! Still not sure why it works this way...

```
function loop() {
    $.get("statusPage.jsp", function(data){
        if(data == 1){
            window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
        }
    });
}
var interval = setInterval(loop, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

try replacing setTimeout with setInterval

Answer (score 0):

```
            setInterval(function() {
                //Use setInterval than setTimeout
           $.get("statusPage.jsp", function(data){
               var loadedData = data;
               if(data == 1){
        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
               }
                });
                   }, 2000);
               });
```

Use setInterVal than setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Their is difference between function **setInterval** AND **setTimeout**
**Explain**:

**setInterval()**

```
The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified      intervals (in milliseconds).

 e.g http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_setinterval
```

**- setTimeout()**

```
  The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.

   e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout
```

Comment: I have tried this with setInterval() and it also does not work.